# R as.POSIXct parsing error

Tags: r, posixct

I am trying to parse a vector of time string and came across a strange error. For example, if I run the following section of code, R returned the result as expected.

```
time_format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"
t_1 = "03/13/2011 01:00:10"
as.POSIXct(t_1, format = time_format)
```

Output:

```
[1] "2011-03-13 01:00:10 EST"
```

However, if I change the time slightly to 2 AM

```
t_2 = "03/13/2011 02:00:10"
as.POSIXct(t_2, format = time_format)
```

The output became:

```
[1] NA
```

I can reproduce it on R 2.11.1 and 2.12.2 on Windows 7 and XP. Does anyone encounter the same problem?

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Cannot reproduce on R version 2.12.0 (2010-10-15) on OS X.

Comment: I think this problem could be specific to Windows. I tried it on XP and win 7 and both produced the same error.

Comment: Nope, it works fine on 32bit Arch Linux box: `"2011-03-13 02:00:10 CET"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You **cannot** parse non-existing times.  02:00:10 did not exist as we had 'spring forward' this Saturday night / Sunday morning with the switch to daylight-savings.  R knows this:

```
R> t_1 = "03/13/2011 01:00:10"; as.POSIXct(t_1, format = time_format)
[1] "2011-03-13 01:00:10 CST"
R> t_2 = "03/13/2011 02:00:10"; as.POSIXct(t_2, format = time_format)
[1] "2011-03-13 01:00:10 CST"
R> t_3 = "03/13/2011 03:00:10"; as.POSIXct(t_3, format = time_format)
[1] "2011-03-13 03:00:10 CDT"
R>
```

On Linux, my timezone library seems to cope -- 02:00:10 becomes 01:00:10 as an hour is subtracted.

Comment: Haha... well I'll be damned! I must test this one after spring forward in Serbia... =)